# Use jquery to append a list of items by a certain count

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 100 items --let's say span tags.

How would I append each item (5 at a time) in new inner div using jquery each and append methods?

```
$.each(items, function (x, result) {

  append to outer-div 5 at a time, each set of spans is inside an inner-div

}

<div class="outer-div>
   <div class="inner-div">
     <span>1</span>
     <span>2</span>
     <span>3</span>
     ... etc.
     <span>5</span>
   </div>
   <div class="inner-div>
     <span>11</span>
     <span>12</span>
     <span>13</span>
     ... etc.
     <span>5</span>
   </div>
  ...etc...
</div>
```

Comment: So, what you want is to group 5 by 5 all the existing `span`s in `outer-div` into `inner-div`s ? Or do you want to generate all the `inner-div`s and `span`s from scratch ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will use a numeric identifier to keep track of how many loops you're doing, create the container when `i` is 1, append each span element to the last `.inner-div` in the document, and reset the counter when it reaches your limit so it will trigger a new `.inner-div` to be created:

```
var i = 1;
$.each(items, function(x, result) {
    // create the container div
    if(i == 1) {
        $('<div/>').addClass('inner-div').appendTo('.outer-div');
    }
    // create child and add to container
    $('.inner-div')
        .last()
        .append(
            $('<span/>').text(result)
        );

    // reset the counter when limit reached
    if(i == 5) {
        i = 1;
    } else {
        // increment counter
        i++;
    }    
});
```

Here's a demo: **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8kw3eu63/1/)**